# What is the best tagging widget?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I was using the [tagging](http://drupal.org/project/tagging) module as my tagging widget until its status changed to `Maintenance status: Unsupported`. Now I'm looking for a replacement. After searching drupal.org I figured out there is not stable tagging widget module for D7:

1. [nice_tags](http://drupal.org/project/nice_tags) only D6
2. [tag_editor](http://drupal.org/project/tag_editor) only D6
3. [active_tags](http://drupal.org/project/active_tags) dev version and not works as expected
4. [community_tags](http://drupal.org/project/community_tags) tagging content in view mode not in add/edit
   form

Is there any other tagging widget which I overlooked?

Comment: I used Tag Clouds http://drupal.org/project/tagclouds . You could try it :-)

Comment: tagclouds provide a block of tags while I looking for tagging widget where you add tags to bundle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use the [Autocomplete Deluxe](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module as tagging widget.

> This is an enhanced autocomplete element, that uses the JQuery UI autocomplete. It will also implement a widget for taxonomy and lists.
>   There is also an implementation for the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module: [Autocomplete Deluxe for References](http://drupal.org/project/acdx_references).

Comment: Right, but it does not work together with Search Autocomplete (http://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) which is a bummer...

Comment: really? I used both in my website and worked, what will happen if I use both?

Comment: See issue here: http://drupal.org/node/1300028

Comment: Is the bug still exists in search_autocomplete 7.x-2.3 version? Issue is about 7.x-2.1

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't realize there's a new version available. I'll have to check. I should probably activate update-notifications for deactivated modules... ^^

Comment: Rrecently good patches for Autocomplete Deluxe and jQuery update, make this module more robust and usable.

Answer (score 2):

Another module to look at is [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen).

> Chosen uses the Chosen jQuery plugin to make your  elements more user-friendly.

Note that it modifies the select list option, to achieve a tagging effect. Major drawback is you can't add new terms this way though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide animation delay, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at MLTag. Uses machine learning algorithms to suggest tags based on your content and tagging history.

Link - https://www.drupal.org/project/mltag